# Android AsyncTask & starting new Activities

Tags: android

I've been having some issues with starting a new activity once an AsyncTask has completed.
I've read that I can put code like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (progress.isShowing()) {
        if (result.equals("true")) {
            progress.dismiss();
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Main.class));
        }
    }
}
```

But basically that just crashes and it's always on the line which it's starting the Activity, It comes up with the error NullPointerException but I can't figure out why?

Any idea?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: `activity` is `null`, maybe? We won't be able to tell w/o more code/logcat information.

Comment: Thank you! You've solved my problem! All I needed to do was pass the Login activity to the AsyncClass and then it worked! Thanks!

Comment: You should add it as an answer and mark it as "accepted" so that others know the solution you found. :)

Comment: Also, `onPostExecute` won't be invoked if the task is cancelled... not sure if that applies to what you are doing (since I noticed you were passing the `result` as an argument and testing whether or not it was `true`).

Comment: Thanks I will do! I have a separate bit for if it's cancelled but the "true" is if the login information is correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that `activity` is not `null`, as it might be the cause of the `NullPointerException`.